# Silverlight viewer on https server needs to access xap file on http server

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, iis-7, silverlight-4.0, https

I have a project which is being hosted on two separate iis servers. Site/server 1 contains the core of the site and is asp.net using https protocol. Site/server 2 is a 3rd party server which contains a silverlight app that I need to reference from site 1.

[image]

Site one has a viewer page for the silverlight control nothing special here other than I load the initparams dynamically to specify server username and a few other params. Where I am having trouble is in a test environment where both servers are http I can access the xap file with no problem. However when I move to a dev/production environment where server 1 (containing the viewer)call the xap file on server 2 the silverlight app will not load. I have on server 2 the following clientaccesspoliy file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*" />
        <domain uri="http://*" />
        <domain uri="https://*" />
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Is it possible to make this call (https to pull a xap file from http)?

Another thought I had was to make both servers use https however in testing this since the iis server certificate is self signed I am getting a security prompt from IE regarding this which causes the app to time out as the trust cannot be verified.

One hack I thought was to override the certificate trust and set ti to true via code but I am not a big fan of this idea.

Can anyone  confirm if what I am trying to accomplish is possible or a suggestion for a different implementation?

thanks in advance

-cheers

**Update**

It looks as if this is not possible due to the security or Silverlight. One option I am now pursuing is to instead leave the the html and xap file on server 2. Instead of trying to load the xap file I am taking the parameters on the click event of the link calling the silverlight control, serializing them and passing them to the secondary server as a serialized object. I can then pass these values into the sl control directly. Not the cleanest approach but it seems to work.